# How To create a foreground task?

Tags: c#, multithreading, task

I seem to fail to create a foreground task.
my main thread is supppose to call another thread and then exit.
the other thread suppose to run forever

```
void MainThreadMain()
{
    task_main = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => OtherThread()) ;
    return;
}

void OtherThread()
{
  while(true)
  {
     TellChuckNorrisJoke();
  }
}
```

how can I ensure task_main will continue running even that Main Thread is dead?
I assumed il do:

```
task_main.IsBackgorund = false;
```

but no such option :\
I can make my main thread to wait a signal from my other thread that it passed to Foreground mode. but thats plain silly.

Comment: You ensure this by *not* using a thread.  Simply call OtherThread() directly, after renaming it of course.

Comment: this post may help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6156878/can-threads-started-by-tasks-parallel-library-act-as-foreground-threads

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The obvious question is: why don't you run your work on the main thread?

Assuming this is not an option, you should use a `Thread` not a `Task`. Then you can set:

```
Thread.IsBackground = false;
```

This will prevent your application from terminating while the worker thread is running.

Comment: I am creating a service. as I understand it the service OnStart method suppose to call another thread and return. if theres no thread to keep program alive it will exit.

Comment: Ah! A Windows Service is controlled by the [Service Control Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685150(v=vs.85).aspx). As such, it does not have a normal "Main Thread". `OnStart` is called by the SCM and you are correct in that it must return quickly. So yes, it makes sense to start a `Thread` ( not a `Task` ). You will also have to implement `OnPause` and `OnStop`. See [MSDN: Windows Service Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y817hyb6.aspx).