# Task status changes to RanToCompletion if the Task await's something

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await, .net-4.5

The question describes the same problem found here - [MSDN Developer Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/edee635c-9534-4a71-8be3-c5ab17d80cff/task-status-changes-to-rantocompletion-after-using-await?forum=winappswithcsharp). The question does not have an accepted answer, neither any of the answers given can be applied to my case (hence a different question).

Question is also derived from one I [asked previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23931937/asynchronous-tasks-waiting-in-main-thread-for-completition), but, due to different nature and more specific problem, I'm asking a new one.

Full code can be found here: http://pastebin.com/uhBGWC5e
* Only thing changed is the task completion check (`while` -> `Task.WhenAll`).

---

When awaiting an async operation inside of a Task, the Task status changes to `RanToCompletion` even though, the Task is still running.

Now, let's see the setup:

```
// Start async.
Task t1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(Accept, s1);
Task t2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(Accept, s1);

Task.WhenAll(t1, t2).Wait();
```

The `Accept` method:

```
public static async void Accept(object state)
{
    TcpListenerEx server = (TcpListenerEx) state;

    IPEndPoint endPoint = server.LocalEndpoint as IPEndPoint;

    Log("Accepting clients on {0}", endPoint);

    while (true)
    {
        var client = server.AcceptTcpClientAsync();

        if (client == null)
        {
            Log("Null error on accept");
            break;
        }

        TcpClient connected = (TcpClient) client;
        servers[server].Add(connected);

        bool stop = await Task<Task<bool>>.Factory.StartNew(Listen, connected).Unwrap();

        if (stop == true)
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    // Stop the server.
    server.Stop();

    Log("Stoppped {0}", endPoint);
}
```

Because of TaskStatus changing to RanToCompletion, the `Task.WhenAll().Wait()` call marks itself finished fairly quickly, resulting in program to be executed further, eventually - terminated.

But, the `Accept` task, in theory, should never stop, it's listening for connections until explicitly stopped.

What is the problem here that's causing the Task to be marked as `RanToCompletion` prematurely?

Comment: Does it have something to do with you using `Task.Factory.StartNew` to invoke an async method, rather than having that method return a `Task`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I can reproduce this issue with far less code:

```
void Main()
{
    Task t1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(Accept);
    t1.Wait();
    Console.WriteLine("Main ended");
}

public static async void Accept()
{
    while (true)
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Stoppped");
}
```

But this works correctly:

```
void Main()
{
    Task t1 = Accept();
    t1.Wait();
    Console.WriteLine("Main ended");
}

public static async Task Accept()
{
    while (true)
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Stoppped");
}
```

Basically, by using `Task.Factory.StartNew()`, you are creating a `Task` based on a separate thread getting spawned to invoke the given delegate (the `Accept()` method). The `Accept` method itself (like any good `async` method) actually returns immediately. So the thread that calls it finishes its task immediately, so the `Task` created to represent that thread also finishes immediately.

If you allow `Accept()` to return a `Task` instead of `void`, then the `Task` that it returns is what you should be awaiting if you want to wait until it has run through all its `await`s.

Comment: Isn't it more correct to say that: it is not the `Accept` method that returns immediately, but the task that does the calling finishes as soon as it calls `Accept`. And that is because `Accept` is defined as async and the task is not required to wait until it actually returns?

Comment: Okay, by making `Accept()` to return `Task` instead of `void` and starting without `Task.Factory` did make the `Task.WhenAll` to wait until completion. The problem now, is, that the nature of `Accept` is broken - it (TcpListener) doesn't respond to more than one connection at a time - the threads are lost (as expected).

Comment: @jolt: There's a lot of code in there, and I'm not entirely sure what you're going for. Could you narrow down your new problem to something more manageable and ask it as a new question?

Comment: @FarhadAlizadehNoori seems like a good point here. Since it returns Task<Task>, wrapper task return immediately after inner task starts. Using Task.Run() will solve this problem.

Comment: @FarhadAlizadehNoori: No. If you look at the code generated when `Accept` method is compiled, the method itself just builds a state machine with some Task continuations, and then returns control back to the calling method before those continuations have executed. The code calling into  `Accept()` has no way of knowing whether `Accept` is marked `async`: nothing about the public signature changes if you remove the `async` keyword: only the behavior of the method itself changes.

Comment: I was having a similar issue with `Task.Run()` of an async method. This explained the issue perfectly; by using Task.Run I'm basically nesting async calls, and the one I actually want to monitor is a layer deeper in the stack than the Task reference I get from `Task.Run()`. Lesson learned, don't mix paradigms; just call the async method and watch the Task you get from it.

Answer (score 13):

There are two things wrong: [`async void`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) and [`Task.Factory.StartNew`](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html). Both of these are bad practices.

First, [`async void` does not allow the calling code to know when it completes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx). So it doesn't matter that you're waiting; the `async void` method will return fairly quickly, and your app can't know when `Accept` actually finishes. To fix this, replace `async void` with the much more proper `async Task`.

Second, [`StartNew` doesn't understand asynchronous delegates](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html). `StartNew` is an extremely low-level API that should not be used in 99.99% of production code. Use `Task.Run` instead.

```
public static async Task Accept(object state);

Task t1 = Task.Run(() => Accept(s1));
Task t2 = Task.Run(() => Accept(s1));
Task.WaitAll(t1, t2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.

I have a reader task which I want to trigger to read data and process it. Therefore I used:

```cs
var readTrigger = new ManualResetEventSlim();
```

In order to gracefully stop the thread whenever it is required I used a CancellationToken. Since I didn't want my task to continuously run and poll data (but use events to signalize new data) I used a blocking function to put the task to sleep when there was nothing to do. Thus I had to listen to both events and this was done using a WaitHandle.

```cs
var action = WaitHandle.WaitAny(new WaitHandle[] { readTrigger.WaitHandle, cancellationToken.WaitHandle });
```

There might be a different, better solution with the WaitHandle with async/await (If somebody knows it please tell me :) )

The function still contains async functions though that I had to wait on. This resulted in a thread function which is async which had the following function header:

```cs
private async Task ReadDataTask(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

The WaitHandle function does blocked waiting until at least one of the events gets triggered. And since I was using WaitHandle I need to use a separate thread to prevent blocking my whole application.
I used the following call to start my Task in a separate thread:

```cs
var t = new Task(async() => await ReadDataTask(ct), ct, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
```

There I had the same problem, that task **t** terminated before the **ReadDataTask** function returned. Since I had to use the WaitHandle (or lets say wanted) non of the former solutions worked for me.

The solution to my problem was fairly simple. I didn't use await to wait for my **ReadDataTask** but used the Wait from the returned task, which resulted in the following call:

```cs
var t = new Task(() => ReadDataTask(ct).Wait(), ct, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
```

I hope I could help you with my solution.

Kind Regards