# Forcing Tasks to create foreground threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, task

Tasks in turn are submitted to ThreadPool which uses background threads. If I want the program to stay running when all work but my tasks is completed, is forcing them to be foreground threads OK ? OR is calling wait() a better idea?

Option A:

```
Task task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(Foo);

public void Foo()
{
   Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground=false;
   //do work
}
```

Option B:

```
Task task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(Foo);
task1.Wait();

public void Foo()
{
   //do work
}
```

EDIT:
This post [Can threads started by Tasks Parallel Library act as foreground threads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6156878) asks a similar question, but the answers are not sufficient. They do not explain the benefits / drawbacks of the options.

Comment: *tasks in turn are submitted to ThreadPool which uses background threads* - is simply wrong that it is very rarely the case.

Comment: @ErikPhilips, can you elaborate?

Comment: [There Is No Thread](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html)

Comment: @ErikPhilips task will use threadpool thread in the case when running synchronous code with `StartNew` as OP shows in the question. Indeed proper async code likely not use threads, but one that is shown by OP is not necessary the best example of asynchronous code.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov sure, I was thinking more about the question in regards to TPL, not [Task.Factory.StartNew() which probably should be avoided as much as possible](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html).

Comment: `Task.Run()` is a safer way to start tasks.

Comment: @AfterWorkGuinness On your edit: feel free to perform your own research on options suggested and ask new concrete questions if you need better explanation of particular concepts. The ways to start/implement tasks and synchronization context are discussed a lot on SO and outside - there is some chance that answer to your questions already there.