# Send SMTP email getting forcibly closed in console application before it can send email in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library, console-application

I have an email notifier application that sends emails out and we do so in a console application that runs every 5 minutes. We run the email part in a task so it can continue onto another group of notifications.

However, we we run one notification, the console closes and the email never gets sent. On the SMTP side it says the host was forcibly closed. How can I keep the console application alive until all tasks are finished, but still be able to multi thread.

> The read operation failed. Bytes transferred: 0 Remote IP:
>   44.444.444.44, Session: 124992, Code: 10054, Message: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

```
private Task SendFromServer(MailMessage mailMessage, bool reuse, bool useServerSmtp)
{
    return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    var smtp = new SmtpClient();
                    smtp.Send(mailMessage);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Logger.Error(ex.InnerException ?? ex);
                }
                finally
                {
                    if(!reuse)
                        mailMessage.Dispose();
                }
            });
        }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps this post will help. I believe it is similar. They mention that an option is to write your own TaskScheduler implementation to address this type of issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6156878/can-threads-started-by-tasks-parallel-library-act-as-foreground-threads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `SmtpClient.SendMailAsync` which can be awaited.

```
private async Task SendFromServer(MailMessage mailMessage) {
    using (var smtp = new SmtpClient()) {
        try {
            await smtp.SendMailAsync(mailMessage);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.Error(ex.InnerException ?? ex);
        }
    }
}
```

and since it is being called in a console application you would need to call it like

```
//get all notification tasks. Assuming notifications => List<MailMessage>
var tasks = notifications.Select(message => SendFromServer(message));
//execute all asynchronously
Task.WhenAll(tasks).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

so the console application waits for all of them to complete their tasks

Comment: It seems to wait until the email is sent, then continues processing the next email.  If I had 100 emails to send, then it would be a queue of 100 instead of them going in parallel. That is just what I see when I breakpoint.

Comment: @MikeFlynn can you show how you process the emails. I get the feeling that this may be an XR problem. I am getting the vibe that you have a list of this call to make and that it should be in a `Task.WhenAll`, but wont be sure till I get  better picture of the bigger system.

Comment: I think that worked.  I keep a list of those tasks stored in a list.  Then at the end of the application I do the WhenAll and it seems to send both without issue now.  I assume there are no downside to this async/wait/whenall stuff?

Comment: @MikeFlynn `Task.WhenAll` and the TPL related API are pretty stable within the framework. I would suggest batching the tasks to help manage available threads.